# how to create two double hung window side by side revit api in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, revit-api, revit, autodesk-bim360

I am new in BIM automation.I want to create multiple window family for revit plugin.I https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-createfamily-revit use this but its creating only 1 double hung window.I need to create custom multiple double hung window family.

pleased help me.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code that you point to is sample code. It is based on the standard Revit SDK sample FamilyCreation/WindowWizard. It shows you the basic principles how to proceed. If you wish to modify it to create multiple different family types within the family definition, it is your job to modify it to do so. To achieve that, you will presumably first have to learn and understand the basic principles of Revit API. This is best achieved by working through the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2). Even [before beginning with the Revit API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/06/extensible-storage-and-renaming-a-family-in-a-project.html#2), however, it will help a lot to understand the basic principles of Revit and its BIM philosophy first. For instance, you need to understand the hierarchical structure of family definition, family types and family instances. So, you will have some learning to do on your own before anybody will be able to help you. I hope this helps and wish you good luck and lots of fun getting started with Forge, BIM, Revit and their APIs.

Comment: ty sir for the reference and suggestion.